# Copy PDF to other folder with OpenFileDialog C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, copy

I tried complete my program, with this code:

```
private void btnBuscar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            FileInfo f = null;
            OpenFileDialog dlg;
            dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
            dlg.Filter = "Document Files (*.doc;*pdf)|*.doc;*pdf";
            dlg.InitialDirectory = Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile.ToString();
            dlg.Title = "Seleccione su archivo de cotización.";
            //Open the Pop-Up Window to select the file
            bool? result = dlg.ShowDialog();
            if (result == true)
            {
                f = new FileInfo(dlg.FileName,);
                using (Stream s = dlg.OpenFile())
                {
                    TextReader reader = new StreamReader(s);
                    string st = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    txtPath.Text = dlg.FileName;
                }
                File.Copy(dlg.FileName,@"C:\Formatos\m1");
            }

        }
```

The problem is when select the file with OpenFileDialog the program Crash automatically. I need copy the files only, and save the path of the copy file in the DB.

Thank you for you help!

Comment: Edit your question and tell us what specific error you are getting when it crashes.

Comment: Set a breakpoint at `dlg.InitialDirectory` and look at what it contains. Then read about [`Environment.GertFolderPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `bool? result = dlg.ShowDialog();` to `if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)`

Also, remove the extra comma from `f = new FileInfo(dlg.FileName,);`

Comment: ShowDialog() returns a nullable bool.